# Highlighting in gvim always goes bold

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I've been working on my own color scheme, ripped out all the references to bold, and yet most identifiers still get bolded.  Working on Gvim in windows. My guess is that there is a default setting that I haven't overridden.

Comment: You may have more luck on the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: ok, thanks!  looks like a great group.  I think I figured out that syncolor.vim is the file that seems to set the bold defaults.  Just not sure if it's good practice to edit that... probably not. ;)